# Rust proof or not the outside of a steel steerer column beneath the stem

Tags: stem, rust, preventative-maintenance

I have a new steel frame which I am building up.  I intend to rust proof this first by using [Waxoyl](http://www.halfords.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_storeId_10001_catalogId_10151_productId_196239_langId_-1_categoryId_165594) made by Hammerite which I will use on the inside of the frame and forks.

Should I use this on the outside of the steerer column ie under the stem etc?  I am worried about the stem slipping with this substance being oil based.  If not is there any way that I can rust proof the outside of the steerer column?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I generally wipe whatever greasy or oily rag I have lying around at the shop on any uncoated steer tubes as a habit. We're in a fairly dry area so it's not of great importance. If I was in a wet area I'd use a product called FrameSaver.

There is no concern with slippage if the steer tube is greasy.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why there is no issue of slippage.  I assume if I put a stem on a greased or oiled steerer column then it is easier for it to rotate.  Thanks

Comment: I think the problem of rust in (quality) steel frames and components is way overstated. I have never seen a rusty steerer tube (beyond surface blemishes).....

Answer (score 1):

Reading that it forms a "flexible waterproof skin" I would have concerns over how thick this stuff is. The stem/steerer tube interface is pretty tight fitting and unless it is completely cured like a paint, I could see it having durability issues when you try to slide the stem on. I think I would just install the stem dry and get it all tightened down and then apply a thin film of waterproof grease with your finger to any areas that might be in contact with the elements or let water in. I am not a fan of grease on this area as it requires additional torque to stop the stem from slipping, but if you do, make sure it is very thin, your pinch bolts have enough torque you should be ok—given the fact that we are talking about a steel steer tube.

Alternatively, when I had one of my frames painted, the entire steerer got a very thin coat of primer, and the rest of the fork was painted with multiple coats of paint. The primer is thin enough that it doesn't affect the OD of the steerer and keeps it completely protected from moisture (this is especially handy since I am using a Thomson stem which has windows that expose the steer tube on each side).